# How to add dynamic classes in VanJS?

Tags: javascript, state, vanjs

I've been playing around with [VanJS](https://vanjs.org/) and building the same app I do with every new JS library I want to try out.

In component/class `DividerList` I'm defining a dynamic HTML class which should have the value `divider-item green` when its *index value divided by the divider* (state which is defined in the parent component App and is given through the component's props) is a natural number, and `divider-item red` if its not a natural number.

The problem is that VanJS does not recalculate the class' value even though the value of divider updates correctly (as can be seen in component Header).

In the documentation I've found [this section about statful binding](https://vanjs.org/tutorial#stateful-binding) but I'm not completely sure if that's the same issue. Furthermore I think implemeting something similar here would be a bit bloated for such a small problem (but I guess if that's the case that would just be the way it is).

```js
const { div, main, button, h1, header } = van.tags;

const Header = ({ divider }) => {
  return header(
    h1(divider),
    " ",
    div(
      { class: "buttons" },
      button({ onclick: () => divider.val++ }, "+"),
      button({ onclick: () => divider.val-- }, "-")
    )
  );
};

const DividerList = ({
  N,
  divider,
}) => {
  return Array.from({ length: N.val }, (_, i) => i + 1).map((i) =>
    div(
      {
        onclick: () => (divider.val = i),
        class: `divider-item ${i % divider.val === 0 ? "green" : "red"}`,
      },
      i
    )
  );
};

const App = () => {
  const divider = van.state(4);
  const N = van.state(100);

  return div(Header({ divider }), main(DividerList({ N, divider })));
};

van.add(document.body, App());
// Alternatively, you can write:
// document.body.appendChild(Hello())
```

```css
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;

  font-family: "Avenir", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  text-align: center;
  color: #2c3e50;
}

header {
  background-color: #8d6e63;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 2rem;
  padding: 1rem;
  /* margin-bottom: 0.5em; */
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.buttons {
  margin-left: 1rem;
}

.buttons button {
  width: 3em;
  height: 3em;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.divider-item {
  padding: 0.5em;
}

.green {
  background-color: #9ccc65;
}

.red {
  background-color: #ef5350;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/vanjs-org/van/public/van-1.1.3.nomodule.min.js"></script>
```

I know VanJS is quite new, but maybe someone can help me figure out why it's not updating.

**Edit**: Even with conditional returns it only sets the correct values for *red* and *green* at the beginning, but doesn't update them:

```
import van, { State } from "vanjs-core";

const { div } = van.tags;

export const DividerList = ({
  N,
  divider,
}: {
  N: State<number>;
  divider: State<number>;
}) => {
  return Array.from({ length: N.val }, (_, i) => i + 1).map((i) => {
    if (i % divider.val === 0) {
      return div(
        {
          onclick: () => (divider.val = i),
          class: "divider-item green",
        },
        i
      );
    } else {
      return div(
        {
          onclick: () => (divider.val = i),
          class: "divider-item red",
        },
        i
      );
    }
  });
};
```

Comment: What is expected output. It is not easy to guess what you mean by `dynamic class which should be dependent on the state divider but its value doesn't change when the divider does `

Comment: Right, I specified the question and hope it's clearer now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not a Van expert either but I believe that its is like other observable frameworks e.g. Solid in that in order for certain things to be reactive they must be enclosed in functions:

```
class: () => `divider-item ${i % divider.val === 0 ? "green" : "red"}`,
```

Actually Solid doesn't need this in the JSX part but it does outside of it, perhaps because Solid is doing stuff at the compilation stage.

And outside the renderer I think you would use `derive` for it to re-compute:

```
// usage = class: classes(i)
const classes = (i) => van.derive(() => `divider-item ${i % divider.val === 0 ? "green" : "red"}`)
```

But since the render function is already reactive to `divider` I think using `van.derive` is redundant:

```
const classes = (i) => () => `divider-item ${i % divider.val === 0 ? "green" : "red"}`
```

Seems to work the same.

```js
const { div, main, button, h1, header } = van.tags;

const Header = ({ divider }) => {
  return header(
    h1(divider),
    " ",
    div(
      { class: "buttons" },
      button({ onclick: () => divider.val++ }, "+"),
      button({ onclick: () => divider.val-- }, "-")
    )
  );
};

const DividerList = ({
  N,
  divider,
}) => {
  return Array.from({ length: N.val }, (_, i) => i + 1).map((i) =>
    div(
      {
        onclick: () => (divider.val = i),
        class: () => `divider-item ${i % divider.val === 0 ? "green" : "red"}`,
      },
      i
    )
  );
};

const App = () => {
  const divider = van.state(4);
  const N = van.state(100);

  return div(Header({ divider }), main(DividerList({ N, divider })));
};

van.add(document.body, App());
// Alternatively, you can write:
// document.body.appendChild(Hello())
```

```css
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;

  font-family: "Avenir", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  text-align: center;
  color: #2c3e50;
}

header {
  background-color: #8d6e63;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 2rem;
  padding: 1rem;
  /* margin-bottom: 0.5em; */
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.buttons {
  margin-left: 1rem;
}

.buttons button {
  width: 3em;
  height: 3em;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.divider-item {
  padding: 0.5em;
}

.green {
  background-color: #9ccc65;
}

.red {
  background-color: #ef5350;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/vanjs-org/van/public/van-1.1.3.nomodule.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I've actually tried `derive` already but in a slightly different way which didn't solve the problem either. But if you know how it's actually done it seems so dumb to even ask :D Anyway thanks for helping.

Comment: I had a little play: https://jsfiddle.net/jcyx6v0b/  since it's calling that function from the render which is already reactive to `divider` and `i` I think the `van.derive` there is redundant 